# Passing query string to form select option

Tags: php, parsing, variables

Hi guys I  have this code that checks linkback:

```
$reciprocal_linkback = reciprocal_linkback("$contenturl","http://www.mydomain.com",1);

if ("$reciprocal_linkback"=="0") {
```

`$contenturl` is the url that will be checked against my website ( http://www.mydomain.com )

The problem is that I need to check the url and the main page. 
I used this code:

```
$parse = parse_url($contenturl);
```

And the result at the end would be this:

```
$parse = parse_url($contenturl);
$reciprocal_linkback = reciprocal_linkback("$contenturl, $parse","http://www.mydomain.com",1);

    if ("$reciprocal_linkback"=="0") {
```

Im not sure how to use multiple variables like `$contenturl, $parse` so I can check both links against my domain.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Sicnerely.

Edit: heres the function

```
function reciprocal_linkback($check_url, $link, $strict = "0") {

    global $global;
    global $field;

    $field['hostname'] = "";
    $field['hostname_port'] = "80";
    $field['result'] = "0";

    preg_match("/^(http:\/\/)?([^\/]+)/i",$check_url, $field['hostname']);

    $field['hostname_short'] = $field['hostname'][2];
    $field['hostname_end'] = str_replace($field['hostname'][0], "", $check_url); # We don't want http://, we want the domain

    $field['url_get'] = fsockopen($field['hostname_short'], $field['hostname_port']); # Connect to domain

    if ($field['url_get']) { # We're connected...

        if(trim($field['hostname_end'])=="") { # No filename, add a slash to end URL

            $field['hostname_page'] = "/";

        } else {

            $field['hostname_page'] = $field['hostname_end']; # Filename

        }

        fputs($field['url_get'], "GET ".$field['hostname_page']." HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ".$field['hostname_short']."\r\n\r\n"); # Request page from domain

        $field['url_content'] = "";

        while(!feof($field['url_get'])) { # Get data by line and store

            $field['url_content'] .= fgets($field['url_get'], 10240);

        }

        if (eregi($link, $field['url_content'])) { # Can we find the URL in the page?

            if ("$strict"=="1") { # Check for nofollow

                $field['result'] = "1"; # Success, we have a link, now check for nofollow

                $field['link_position'] = strpos($field['url_content'], $link); # Find position of URL being checked

                $field['link_html_end'] = substr($field['url_content'],($field['link_position'] + strlen($link)),200); # Get HTML after URL
                $field['link_html_start'] = substr($field['url_content'],($field['link_position'] - strlen($link) - 100),200); # Get HTML before URL

                $field['link_html_end_explode'] = explode(">",$field['link_html_end']);
                $field['link_html_start_explode'] = explode("<",$field['link_html_start']);

                $link_html_start_count = count($field['link_html_start_explode']) - 1;
                $field['link_html_start_explode'] = explode("=",$field['link_html_start_explode'][$link_html_start_count]);

                $field['link_html_tag'] = $field['link_html_end_explode'][0].$field['link_html_start_explode'][0]; # Get link HTML, without URL and surrounding HTML

                if (eregi("nofollow", $field['link_html_tag'])) { # Can we find a nofollow tag in link HTML?

                    $field['result'] = "0"; # Nofollow tag found

                }

            } else {

                $field['result'] = "1"; # Success, we have a link, but nofollow not checked

            }
        }

        fclose($field['url_get']);

    } else {

        $field['result'] = "2"; # Cannot read page

    }

    return $field['result'];

}
```

And the complete code i mention above:

```
// Check to see if have backlink and nofollow atribute

$reciprocal_linkback = reciprocal_linkback("$contenturl","http://www.dumpvid.com",1);

if ("$reciprocal_linkback"=="0") {

$_SESSION['submitstatus'] = "<div class=error><b>Error:</b> Backlink was not found, or nofollow detected.</div> ";
header('Location: '.$frompage.'');
 exit; 

}
```

I need to make it check the url itself and the domain from that same url.

thats why i used the $parse = parse_url($contenturl); to transform the url in domain.tld only, but dint worked.

Comment: Why do you put variables inside a quotes? Shouldn't it be like that: `reciprocal_linkback($contenturl, $parse,"http://www.mydomain.com",1)`? It will be useful if you'll post the function itself. If `$contenturl` and `$parse` are both links and you want to check both of them in this function you should call it twice or modify the function itself.

Comment: I grabed this code from a tutorial and its working well i guess, i just dont know how to change it in order to acomplish my needs, any sugestion  would be appreciated

Comment: I updated tmy first post and added the complete function so you can analyse better. thanks for now

Comment: Can you show a specific example of what you want to do? `parse_url` function returns an array which contains different parts of the url. Give a specific example of `$contenturl` and `$parse`.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. this is to be used in a dump link site, this function will check the submit form and if dont finds a backlink on the domain that in this case is $contenturl will no let the user to submit the form, this variable calls the the url for the content that the user is trying to submit, well everything is working till here, the $parse variable is because i need it to parse the url and transform it just in domain.tld so the script will check the url for the content and the main page. Hope you understand my explanation

Comment: i just need to have the script checking $contenturl that is the url submited by the user ie: http://www.domain.com/video_content.html and at the same time i need it to check also the main page ie: http://domain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
$contenturl = "http://domain.com/video_content.html";
$parse = parse_url($contenturl);
$base_url = $parse["host"]; // domain.com
```

And call it twice:

```
$linkback1 = reciprocal_linkback($contenturl, "http://www.mydomain.com", 1);
$linkback2 = reciprocal_linkback($base_url, "http://www.mydomain.com", 1);
```

Comment: hi cthulhu thanks for replying, how can i make the if statments for the 2 conditions?

Comment: @DaniQueiroga - If you want the condition to be true only when both `$linkback1` and `$linkback2` are "0" then do: `if($linkback1 == "0" && $linkback2 == "0")`

Comment: thanks cthulhu i figure it out and its working, thanks a lot for your time . Nice hollydays cheers